# Binomial Theorem Year 12 Question

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

[image]

Not sure what to do here. The proof part is very simple you change the respect ${}^{n}C_{r}$ and ${}^{n-1}C_{r-1}$ into fraction form.

I tried in the next part to expand using the $$ P_r $$ equation that they gave and then factoring $x \, (1-x)$ out but I'm not sure how to use the equation that I had proved in answering the question.

Comment: Just any direction of what to do would be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The binomial coefficient is defined by
$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k! \, (n-k)!}.$$
Now,
$$k \, \binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{(k-1)! \, (n-k)!} = n \, \frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)! \, ((n-1) - (k-1))!} = n \, \binom{n-1}{k-1}. $$
The remainder is to follow.

Using the binomial expansion
$$(a + b)^{n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \, a^{n-k} \, b^{k}$$
then
$$ \sum_{r=0}^{n} P_{r} = \sum_{r=0}^{n} \binom{n}{r} \, x^{r} \, (1-x)^{n-r} = (x + 1-x)^{n} = 1^{n} = 1.$$

For the second consider:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} k \, P_{k} &= \sum_{k=1}^{n} k \binom{n}{k} \, x^{k} \, (1-x)^{n-k} \\
&= n \, \sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n-1}{k-1} \, x^{k} \, (1-x)^{n-k} \\
&= n \, \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{k} \, x^{k+1} \, (1-x)^{n-1-k} \\
&= n \, x \, ((1-x) + x)^{n-1} = n \, x.
\end{align}